# Visual Studio 2016 Stacked Bar Graph Legend: Change Label Title

Tags: reporting-services, charts, legend

Is there a way to change the label of the legend? I need the blue Legend to say “Incident Type”.

Thank you.  
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on a series, or right click on a field in the values area, and select **Series Properties**.
2. Click **Legend** and write an expression for the custom legend text box.
3. `=Switch(
   Fields!ProcessMedRec.Value="Series1", "Incident Type"
   )`

[image]